# Rails routes resources - add extra param on all routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I wanna generate some routes for my scaffold, but in some way that all of then looks something like:

```
/companys/:type
/companys/:type/new
/companys/:type/:id/edit
```

so I can catch that "type" param on my controllers. I don't wanna do it manually... Is there some way to easily add that :type param? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resources :companys, path: '/companys/:type'`

It's worth nothing that the inflector will pluralize `company` to `companies` instead of companys.

Comment: worked like a charm! Gonna mark you answer... Thank you =)